# PowerShell out-file double space separator

Tags: powershell

How do I write this out to a file but have each var separated by a double space?

```
$localfiles | Select-Object MD5 , fullname | Out-File "P:\scripts\md5.sum" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I want it to look like this: - note the double space between the md5 and the full name var

```
asfdsdf34534534  this\is\my\fullname
```

Local files is a var that has at least those TWO select objects if not more

```
$localfiles.GetType()                     


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Here is were the localFile var is being set:

```
$localfiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Tony\Pictures" -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $lastrun } |
select-object name, fullname, @{Name = "MD5"; Expression = { (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash.ToLower() } } |
select-object name, MD5, @{Name = 'fullname'; Expression = { $_.FullName.Replace('\', '/').Replace('C:/Users/Tony/','My ') }}
```

Comment: `Out-File` doesn't have a `-NoTypeInformation` switch, are you trying to export to a Csv? It's not clear what's your expected output

Comment: Can you give us an example of the current output, and what you want it to be?

Comment: What is `$localfiles`

Comment: Updated OP to include getType

Comment: Careful with out-file -append.  It can mix ascii and utf16 encodings.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're looking to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |
ForEach-Object { '{0}  {1}' -f $_.Hash, $_.Path } |
Out-File "P:\scripts\md5.sum"
```

---

```
$localFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Tony\Pictures" -Recurse -File |
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $lastrun } |
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | ForEach-Object {
    '{0}  {1}' -f $_.Hash.ToLower(), $_.Path.Replace('\', '/').Replace('C:/Users/Tony/','My ')
}

$localFiles | Out-File "P:\scripts\md5.sum" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Updated OP on the type of localFiles var as this is not what I’m looking for

Comment: @Tony there you go, I updated my answer.

Comment: I get all kinds of weird nulls 

 6 f 1 b e 6 d 2 5 e 5 0 0 3 1   maybe some unicode/format thing

Comment: @Tony that's why I mentioned on my answer that without know how `$localFiles` is being created I cannot test the code.

Comment: updated OP with the line of code where that is being set

Comment: @Tony got it, do you want to include the headers (`MD5` and `FullName`) to the exported file or just the data?

Comment: Just the data pls

Comment: @Tony I updated my answer, that worked fine for me if you still see nulls on the hash I'm unsure what could it be.

Comment: Thanks - but I want that out-file to happen at a different time than the sum and file path steps - how do I do that ?

Comment: @Tony Updated however I feel you already knew how to do that....

Comment: thanks - one final thing - I'm noticing with the out-file its not putting the first entry on a new line.. it just gets appended to the end of the last line vs it creating a new line and then inserting data